# How to randomize bevel weight modifier through geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, bevel, vertex-weights

I am trying to randomize the width of the bevel modifier by creating random values through geometry nodes. I managed to create attributes and create a vertex group that the bevel node takes in, which seemed to work. However, it doesnt seem like it looks at the values each of the vertices have. I looked around and i believe that this is either broken or simply not supported. Should this attribute be created for vertex or edges? Ultimately i think it would need to take in a combination of a selection of vertices to bevel, and the weight values.

[image]
Part of the confusion is that if i created an attribute on the mesh itself it should be able to read it? Even the manual says that the Bevel Modifier is expecting an attribute called "bevel_weight" however no matter what i do, the modifier simply does not read it.
[image]

Comment: Hello. You need to use "Vertex Group" option instead of "Weight". Bevel weight are a special data type that is not stored in the same place as vertex group (AFAIK)

Comment: The attribute "bevel_weight" is actually a built-in attribute that cannot be influenced with *Geometry Nodes*, but can only be applied to parts of the mesh in *Edit Mode*. The only possibility you have, and @Gorgious already mentioned this correctly, is that you control it via vertex groups. But you have no possibility to define the intensity of the bevel there.

Comment: Oh, right the vertex group option is an on / off type of thing, so you can't vary the bevel amount unfortunately. I'm sure down the line they'll implement a way to do it, or even implement the bevel node, but at the moment you can't.

Comment: If anyone's interested, here's a video showcasing progress and problems with this feature https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=16dpUQ57Xv8&t=1s

Comment: Thank you everyone for answering my question. It's a shame that this isn't supported yet. I'm looking forward to this new bevel node.

Comment: this isn't posted just yet. I believe the blender devs are planing on making more attributes generic and able to be influenced by geometry node. however, it isn't possible now, and I'm not sure if this speed attribute is on their plans for anytime soon

Answer (score 3):

they just added the functionality now, so you can use the attributes `bevel_weight_vert` and `bevel_weight_edge` to set the weight for the bevel modifier from GN.

See here:
https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/pulls/108023

here is an image example (it forsure works in 4.0.
[image]

Comment: What version of Blender has this update? This is very exciting news!

Comment: Sadly it doesnt look like it works unless im doing something wrong. Downloaded version 3.6 to text. In the link you provided, it looks like they are adding the weight by hand, and making sure the weight is retained when instanced and or "joined". Or at least that is what it looks like to me.

Comment: @Raul Note: Unfortunately, this technique is currently only available from version 4.0 (as of July 9, 2023) ...and this is only downloadable in an early alpha version: https://builder.blender.org/download/daily/archive/

Comment: My apologies, i got excited and didnt see that it was for Blender 4. Thank you so much for letting me know!