# How to randomise bevel weight?

Tags: geometry-nodes, bevel, texture-coordinates, vertex-weights

[This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/293393/177524) has a noise texture control the value of the `bevel_weight_edge` attribute in geometry nodes – but it doesn't work for me (the texture is too stretched):

[image]

Is there another way to randomise bevel weight? (Or a fix to the texture stretching?)

[image]

Comment: If you are rendering with cycles, you could use the bevel shading node.

Comment: @Leander How though?

Answer (score 0):

You can change to the following:

[image]

Your vertex group input should be a string and its value retreived using "named attribute".

And from that, simply plug a random node into the bevel weight value.

---

From your question in comments: how to define bevel weight from the vertices of a vertex group:

[image]

This samples the vertex group from the edge vertex indices, and check if the vertices have a non null value in this vertex group.

And from that, assign a bevel weight to `bevel_weight_edge` attribute.

Of course you can change things above: for instance, should the edge be bevelled because only one vertex has a weight in the vertex group (using `or` instead of `and`), or other.

Comment: Is there a way to make it random across a single edge like the answer I linked?

Comment: You mean using the vertex group like in your file, or a random edge?

Comment: Just the edges bevelled from vertex group.

Comment: I'm sorry what is the second set up meant to be doing? I should have been more clear: I want the bevel weight to vary within edges, [like this](https://imgur.com/3fDkq8M)

Comment: Well, no it was not clear: an edge is delimited by two vertices. The link you just provided has subdivision. So you need to subdivide the mesh (as you want) and set random bevel. The way it should be subdivided is to determinate, but GN won't be able to do it like in your image (as there will be horizontal subdivisions).

Comment: So it's not possible?

Comment: With the mesh as it is in the question, no this is not possible using gn except subdividing all the mesh parts (like subdivision modifier does using "simple" option).